# Apache Echarts: dataZoom's miniature misrepresents data in a managed plot (the plot drawn over the slider doesn't match the main plot's data)

Tags: javascript, user-interface, charts, echarts

When I create simple [line plot/chart](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.type) using Apache Echarts I also can add built-in data scaling mechanism: [dataZoom](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataZoom). It reaches its main goal, but there is a question to scaled data representation, made by dataZoom. By default, dataZoom doesn't take into account the chart scale [limits](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.min) ticks or/and the minimum and maximum allowable values ([range of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_function), represented by the plot). Instead, the thumbnail of the chart is drawn on the specific value range passed to the plot in [series](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series) section. In addition, everytime a small indent is added from the minimum and maximum values ​​to the borders of the graphic element.

As a result, the representation of the visualised data looks inconsistent with reality: null is not null, max is not max (because they don't match the lower and higher bounds of the coordinate area of ​​the thumbnail plot, respectively), the amplitude of the chart fluctuations does not correspond to the scale of real data fluctuations.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg1zj.png)

Is there a way (documented or undocumented) to remove the indents and force the plot to use the minimum and maximum values ​​allowed for the yAxis ticks?

I drawn a small example, it may be pasted to Echarts [online editor](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=area-simple).

```
let x = [];
let y = [];
let scaled = [];
/*y = [
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 300, 300, 
  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
];*/
for (let i = 1; i < 300; i++) {
  x.push(i);
  element = Math.random() * 40 + 50;
  y.push(element);
  scaled.push(element * 6 - 250);
}
option = {
  xAxis: {
    data: x
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 300
  },
  dataZoom: [
    {
      start: 50,
      end: 58.5
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Fake Data',
      type: 'line',
      symbol: 'none',
      data: y
    },
    {
      name: 'Simulated Scaling',
      type: 'line',
      symbol: 'none',
      lineStyle: {
        opacity: 0.3
      },
      data: scaled
    }
  ]
};
```

As you can see, the magnitude of the fluctuations of the graph, drawn by dataZoom doesn't correspond rather to the main data, but to some kind of artificial transformation of them (light green graph). Then try to comment 11st line and uncomment lines from 4 to 7. At the start of the plot you'll see main graph touching y zero line, but not on the thumbnail.

I didn't find any [params](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataZoom) for dataZoom that make them to look like expected.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.